# Unable to give proper padding to Logo and menu in navbar

Tags: html, css

I am new to frontend developement and currently in learning phase I am trying to style navbar where I have brand title on left and menus on the right side.

```css
body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Segoe UI, Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, Fira Sans, Droid Sans, Helvetica Neue, sans-serif;
}

.navigation {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding-right: 50px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<nav className='navigation'>
  <div className="logo">
    <Link href="#">Bozo</Link>
  </div>
  <div className="menu">
    <ul>
      <li className="menu-items">
        <Link href="/">Home</Link>
      </li>
      <li className="menu-items">
        <Link href="/about">About</Link>
      </li>
      <li className="menu-items">
        <Link href="/contact">Contact</Link>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Below is the screenshot attached in which menus gets hidden on the right:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using a tag Link rather than an HTML a (anchor) tag? Are you using some preprocessor that you haven't shown?

Comment: I am using Nest.js here

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Segoe UI, Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, Fira Sans, Droid Sans, Helvetica Neue, sans-serif;
}

.navigation {
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu {
  width: 60%;
}

.menu ul {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<nav class='navigation'>
  <div class="logo">
    <Link href="#">Bozo</Link>
  </div>
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li class="menu-items">
        <Link href="/">Home</Link>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-items">
        <Link href="/about">About</Link>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-items">
        <Link href="/contact">Contact</Link>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: looks good but you don't need width:100vw - divs are 100% wide by default